# Java Two-Dimensional Array

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

The two-dimensional array of boolean values that will be referenced by matrix will be used to simulate an LED-based display that can hold LETTERS_PER_DISPLAY letters.

Modify the constructor to create a two-dimensional array of boolean that has FONT_LETTER_HEIGHT rows and (FONT_LETTER_WIDTH times LETTERS_PER_DISPLAY) columns and assign it to the instance variable matrix.

```
public class LEDDisplay
{
   private boolean[] = matrix;
   private static final int FONT_LETTER_HEIGHT = 5;
   private static final int FONT_LETTER_WIDTH = 6;
   private static final int LETTERS_PER_DISPLAY = 10;

public LEDDisplay()
{
    boolean[][] matrix = new boolean[FONT_LETTER_HEIGHT][FONT_LETTER_WIDTH]
}
```

Please could you tell me whether my constructor is correct?

Comment: You are misreading the second requirement. Read again. (It's wrong in the answers, too)

Comment: Is each boolean representing one LED?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it's actually not correct - you hide the member variable matrix by defining a local to the constructor one. Here is the correct way:

```
public class LEDDisplay
{
   private boolean[][] matrix;
   private static final int FONT_LETTER_HEIGHT = 5;
   private static final int FONT_LETTER_WIDTH = 6;
   private static final int LETTERS_PER_DISPLAY = 10;

public LEDDisplay()
{
    matrix = new boolean[FONT_LETTER_HEIGHT][FONT_LETTER_WIDTH * LETTERS_PER_DISPLAY];
}
```

Comment: May be you have to multiply FONT_LEETER_WIDTH with LETTERS_PER_DISPLAY because OP has written: "*FONT_LETTER_WIDTH times LETTERS_PER_DISPLAY*"

Answer (score 1):

Your one dimentional array matrix is class variable whereas matrix in constructor is local to the constructor and not visible outside the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

> FONT_LETTER_HEIGHT rows and (FONT_LETTER_WIDTH ***times***
>   LETTERS_PER_DISPLAY) columns

That should be:

```
new boolean[FONT_LETTER_HEIGHT][FONT_LETTER_WIDTH * LETTERS_PER_DISPLAY]
```

> and assign it to the instance variable matrix.

```
public LEDDisplay()
{
    matrix = new boolean[FONT_LETTER_HEIGHT][FONT_LETTER_WIDTH]
}
```

However

```
boolean[][] matrix = new boolean[FONT_LETTER_HEIGHT][FONT_LETTER_WIDTH]
```

creates a *local* variable `matrix` that is visible only in the constructor. This will have no effect on the instance variable `matrix`.

Answer (score 0):

Two small probs with the code:

1. matrix is defined as a member variable of the class, should be defined as a 2-D array, and then does not need to be re-defined in the constructor
2. the original post states that there should be

> "(FONT_LETTER_WIDTH times LETTERS_PER_DISPLAY) columns"

and your constructor only includes FONT_LETTER_WIDTH

Something like this:

```
public class LEDDisplay
{
   private boolean[][] matrix;
   private static final int FONT_LETTER_HEIGHT = 5;
   private static final int FONT_LETTER_WIDTH = 6;
   private static final int LETTERS_PER_DISPLAY = 10;

public LEDDisplay()
{
    matrix = new boolean[FONT_LETTER_HEIGHT][FONT_LETTER_WIDTH * LETTERS_PER_DISPLAY];
}
```